# C# Remove a letter that trails a number from multiple instances in a string whether with Regex by another method

Tags: c#, regex

I have a log giving me messages that look like this

`Error Message: "  Expected: 660m  But was:  600m" Error Message: "  Expected: 358m  But was:  325m" Error Message: "  Expected: 1088m  But was:  995m" Error Message: "  Expected: 69.82m  But was:  67.96m" Error Message: "  Expected: 1157.82m  But was:  1062.96m"`

I want to remove the 'm' trailing the numbers. I have attempted to use`Regex.Replace()` and I can select the entire pattern every time but now I need to replace it with just the digit component. My code for selecting

```
example = Regex.Replace(example,"[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{1}", "");
```

Is there a way to just select the 'm' and replace it in every instance of the Regex pattern?

Comment: Hmm, you probably have a purpose in parsing that log but it does look like .NET unit test output that is just being very precise by showing that the values are of type Decimal. (C# literal Decimal values have an m suffix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capturing group with a replacement backreference in the replacement pattern:

```
example = Regex.Replace(example, @"([0-9])[a-zA-Z]\b", "$1");
```

Note the `\b` word boundary after the letter pattern, it is used to make sure the letter is at the end of the word.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B0-9%5D%29%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5Cb&i=Error%20Message%3A%20%22%20%20Expected%3A%20660m%20%20But%20was%3A%20%20600m%22%20Error%20Message%3A%20%22%20%20Expected%3A%20358m%20%20But%20was%3A%20%20325m%22%20Error%20Message%3A%20%22%20%20Expected%3A%201088m%20%20But%20was%3A%20%20995m%22%20Error%20Message%3A%20%22%20%20Expected%3A%2069.82m%20%20But%20was%3A%20%2067.96m%22%20Error%20Message%3A%20%22%20%20Expected%3A%201157.82m%20%20But%20was%3A%20%201062.96m%22&r=%241). Result:

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `([0-9])` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `$1`) matching any one digit
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary